# How to simulate and minimize the price impact by splitting a large purchase into smaller chunks and over a number of days?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3, trading

Let's say a trading firm wants to buy $5 MIL worth of SYN (https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/synapse) in Uniswap V3 pools. SYN currently has a market cap of $135 MIL. I know how to calculate the price impact if it is to purchase it all at once.

But in practice, to minimize price impact, one would split this 5 MIL into `x` number of smaller purchases over `y` number of days. How can I simulate this so I can find the optimal `x` and `y` (aka maximize the number of SYN tokens with $5 MIL), while using actual historical price and liquidity pool data at Uniswap V3?